# How to create filter expression dynamically in EF IQueryable?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, expression, iqueryable

Lets say we have interface:

```
public interface ISystemCompany
{
    Guid SystemCompanyId { get; set; }
}
```

We also have `IQueryable<>` of type, that implements `ISystemCompany`.

We have specific SystemCompanyId value: `432486bc-95f2-e111-be6e-74de2b99e249`

We want to write function, that filters IQueryable by value of this field. This is example of function like that:

```
public IQueryable FilterByValue(IQueryable listToFilter, Guid valueToFilter)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object)); 
    // item
    var converted = Expression.Convert(parameter, typeof(ISystemCompany)); 
    // (ISystemCompany)item
    var member = Expression.Property(converted, "SystemCompanyId"); 
    // ((ISystemCompany)item).SystemCompanyId
    var comparison = Expression.Equal(member, Expression.Constant(valueToFilter)); 
    // ((ISystemCompany)item).SystemCompanyId == valueToFilter
    var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, bool>>(comparison, new[] { parameter } ); 
    //item => ((ISystemCompany)item).SystemCompanyId == valueToFilter
    return ((IQueryable<object>)listToFilter).Where(expression); 
    // listToFilter.Where(((ISystemCompany)item).SystemCompanyId == valueToFilter)
}
```

This function doesn't work with Entity Framework, because it doesn't support deferred execution. How can I improve it to introduce this support?

Comment: I may miss something, but why don't you work with generics ? `IQueryable<T>` instead of casting listToFilter to `IQueryable<object>` ?

Comment: @Raphaël Althaus: There is no T. I only get IQueryable and value field on entry. Function header needs to stay that way.

Comment: I doubt this will work even if you get the expression correct because LINQ to EF does not support interfaces.

Comment: Eranga: That is why I need to get rid of interfaces. I need to filter by field. There is no need to use interface.